# AngularJS + SailsJS ng-file-upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, upload, sails.js, ng-file-upload

could you recommend me an example of Sails.Js + Angular.js for upload files to the server and then views them. I've reviewed a lot of examples, but neither is suitable.
When i try to download every time i get error in console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:1337/analyzes/upload. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''. Origin localhost:3000 is therefore not allowed access.

part of my AngularJS controller (with ng-file-upload module):

```
    $scope.upload = function (file) {
    Upload.upload({
        url: AppSettings.serverUrl+'/analyzes/upload',
        data: {file: file}
    }).then(function (resp) {
        console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
};
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="button" ngf-select="upload($file)">Upload on file select</div>
```

And my Sails.JS controller (also i have empty model): 
module.exports = {

```
  upload: function  (req, res) {
    req.file('analyzes').upload(function (err, files) {

      if (err)
        return res.serverError(err);

      return res.json({
        message: files.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
        files: files
      });
    });
  }
};
```

I feel that the source of the problem is that I use a separate URL to display website (localhost:3000) and other for Sails.Js (localhost:1337).

I'am using this https://github.com/jakemmarsh/angularjs-gulp-browserify-boilerplate for front end

And sory for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; the problem has to do with your Sails app not allowing localhost:3000. Check out the documentation at http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-cors.

Basically, you need to allow localhost:3000 through CORS.
From the above documentation

```
'/foo/bar': {
  target: 'FooController.bar',
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://foobar.com,https://owlhoot.com',
    methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD'
  }
}
```

where `origin` is http://localhost:3000, in your case. And also don't forget to replace the endpoint route and `target`.

Comment: thank's for answer. However, i dont know what kind of code should be in FooController.bar. May be you have example??

Comment: i put this code
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  sails.log.debug("Header GO");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD');
  next();
};
and nothing happened

Comment: Did you insert the suggested code (with the modifications required for your case) to `/config/cors.js`? You're not supposed to create a FooController, it's just an example. The syntax there is basically `YourControllerName.yourFunctionName`...

Comment: @ДмитрийКраснов I would read and make sure you understand what is going on in the above documentation I linked. You're likely (extremely likely) to run into more trouble by just copy-pasting config code you find on the internet.

Comment: thank you very much for your responsiveness. I'm really understand that the "copy-paste" is no way. In my project, when i put this code "'/analyzes/upload': {
    controller: "AnalyzesController",
    cors: {
      origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
      methods: 'GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD'
    }
  }" to config/polices.js, sails looking for polices/AnalyzesController.js. And another option - it's change cors.js, but all option doesn't work. i'm really need good and complete example.